There is a malfunction in my local repository branch
Yesterday, I encountered a commit conflict while fetching from my upstream. In my limited knowledge, I deleted the file with the commit conflict from my vs code. Now, I tried to fetch from my upstream with the hope that I'll still have access to the file but I could not find it. I also observed that the background colour of my branch in my terminal switched from yellow to green. How do I resolve this? I'm a beginner so, I am freaking out already.
I tried checking out to my main branch and then back to my branch. I thought that would change it to the original colour- yellow but it remained the same.

Can you see the file on github.com? If so, it’s still on the repo (and you should probably git fetch or just git clone a new copy of the repo to VS Code, or even just redownload the file manually from GitHub).
If you can’t see the file, maybe look through your other branches to see if you can find a copy. However, if it isn’t visible on github.com, it’s probably gone.
